# Is it true that if $H,K$ are two normal subgroups of $G$ such that $G=HK$ an $H\cap K = \{1\},$ then $G/H \cong K?$

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups, direct-product

Determine whether the following is true or false. 
Note that $\cong$ means group isomorphic.

> Question: Is it true that if $H,K$ are two normal subgroups of $G$ such that $G=HK$ an $H\cap K = \{1\},$ then $G/H \cong K?$

My attempt: 
I think the statement is true.

Since $G=HK,$ for every $g\in G,$ there exists $h\in H$ an $k\in K$ such that $g=hk.$
Define $\phi:G\to K$ by 
$$\phi(g) = h^{-1}g.$$
Note that $h^{-1}g\in K.$
If $g$ has two representations, say $g= h_1k_1 = h_2k_2,$ then $h_2^{-1}h_1= k_2k_1^{-1}.$
Since $H\cap K = \{1\},$ so $h_2^{-1}h_1 = 1,$ which implies that $h_1=h_2.$
So $\phi$ is well-defined. 
Note that kernel of $\phi$ is $H$ and $\phi$ is surjective. 
By first isomorphism theorem for group, we have 
$$G/ H \cong K.$$

Is my attempt correct?

---

On the other hand, I notice that $G$ is the internal direct product of $H$ and $K.$
Therefore, $G \cong H\times K.$ 
Can I conclude here that $G/H\cong K?$

Comment: Yes, that works

Comment: You have a stronger result: $G\cong H\times K$.

Comment: @Batominovski how to prove that $G\cong H \times K$ implies that $G/H \cong K?$

Comment: If $G$ is the ***internal*** direct product $H\times K$, then $G/H\cong K$ via the map sending each $gH\in G/H$ to $k$, where $k$ is the unique element of $K$ such that $g=hk$ for some $h\in H$.  $$\phantom{a}$$ However, **be warned**: the following is *not* true.  "Let $G$ be the ***external*** direct product $H\times K$ of groups $H$ and $K$.  If a normal subgroup $N$ of $G$ is isomorphic to $H$, then $G/N\cong K$."